# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{e^n+e^{-n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to check, whether $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{e^n+e^{-n}}$ converges or diverges.

Unfortunately i have no good idea how to start, the Comparison test with $\frac{1}{e^n}$ was just as little helpfull as Ratio test, which failed...

Comment: $i$ is the imaginary unit, $i^2 = -1$? Why did comparison with $1/e^n$ not help?

Comment: i had $\frac{e^{in}}{1+e^{2n}}$ in the end

Comment: $e^{in}$ doesn't get big, its size never changes.

Comment: why is that? so it converges?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{e^n+e^{-n}} \le \frac{1}{e^n}$ and $|e^{in}| = 1$. These two facts can help a lot...

Comment: $|a_k|=|\frac{e^{in}}{e^n+e^{-n}}|=\frac{1}{e^n+e^{-n}}\le \frac{1}{e^n}=b_k$. Since $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} b_k$ converges, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_k|$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the comparison test didn't work for you. Perhaps you were confused about the complex exponential? In that case, please read up on Euler's formula ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)):

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$

Notably, $|e^{ix}| = 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Applying this to your series, we can make the following estimates:

$$\left|\frac{e^{in}}{e^{-n} + e^n}\right| = \left|\frac1{e^{-n}+e^n}\right| < e^{-n}$$

where the last inequality follows as $e^{-n} + e^n > e^n$. Now since

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n} = \frac1{1-e^{-1}}$$

it follows from the comparison test that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{in}}{e^{-n}+e^n}$$

converges as well.